# Works if I execute it manually on the agent but it doesn't if Jenkins execute it as a part of the pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-build, docker-buildkit

I'm trying to build a docker image as a part of my project's pipeline and pass some credentials as secrets. The compromised line is

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME --secret id=ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD -f "$DOCKERFILE" context
```

I'm getting the following error

```
could not parse secrets: [id=ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME id=ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD]: failed to stat ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME: stat ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME: no such file or directory
```

The strange thing is that this works in the same machine where Jenkins executes it if I execute it manually.

Is there something that Jenkins does between starting the execution and reaching the script that could be messing with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Jenkins agent doesn't have the Environment Variables set.
You could do a `printenv` or an `echo` to check this in your pipeline.

But it is worth checking around your logic that sets these env vars in the pipeline.